# Learning to read mathese - how do I interpret $(c_j = a + (j - \frac{1}{2}) \Delta x$

Tags: calculus

$(c_j = a + (j - \frac{1}{2}) \Delta x$

I am trying to learn the midpoint rule for approximation of the area under a curve but I can't translate this into something I can work with.

The formula to memorize is $M_n = \Delta x ( f(c_1) ... f(c_n))$

simple enough

So

$\int_0^2 x^2 dx$

So my $\Delta x$ is $\frac{1}{2}$

$c_1 = 0 + (1 - \frac{1}{2}) * \frac{1}{2}$

$c_2 = 0 + (2 - \frac{1}{2}) * \frac{1}{2}$

$c_3 = 0 + (3 - \frac{1}{2}) * \frac{1}{2}$

Is that correct or is it really suppose to be $j= \Delta x$?

$c_{\frac{1}{2}} = 0 + (\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2}) * \frac{1}{2}$

This also doesn't make sense to me, where do I begin? And how do I interpret this.

Comment: Can you give us some idea of what any of these letters mean?

Comment: $c_j$ is the midpoint of the $j$'th interval. "$c_{1\over 2}$" makes no sense. In your example, with $\Delta x=1/2$, there are four intervals, each of length $\Delta x$: $[0,1/2]$, $[1/2,1]$, $[1,3/2]$, and $[3/2,2]$. Note the right endpoint of the $j$'th interval is $0+ j\cdot \Delta x$.  To get to the midpoint of the $j$'th interval, you subtract $(1/2)\Delta x$ from the right endpoint. This gives your formula.

Comment: @DavidMitra But that isn't what is stated in the book. In the book it claims that I need to use j.  $(c_j = a + (j - \frac{1}{2}) \Delta x$ Do they mean $\Delta x * j$?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. How can $j$ be $1/2$? $j$ is one of $1,2,3,4$. You need to compute $c_{\color{maroon}4}=0+(4-(1/2))(1/2)$. Now that you have the values of all the $c_j$'s, compute $M_n$ according to your formula (your formula for $M_n$ is missing some addition signs).

Comment: My formula for M_n is exaclty as the book states.

Comment: They indeed mean $(j-1/2)\cdot\Delta x$. The quantity $\Delta x\cdot j$ is the right-hand endpoint of the $j$'th interval. You want the midpoint of the interval; hence the "$-1/2$".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$M_n = \Delta x \left( f(c_1) + \cdots + f(c_n)\right)$$

$$c_j = 0 + \left(j - \dfrac 12\right)\Delta x = j\Delta x - \dfrac {\Delta x}{2}$$

Now, why would you put $j =1/2$?

$\;j$ is either $\;1, \,2, \,3,\;\text{or}\;4.$ You've computed $c_1 - c_3$, but still need to compute $$c_4=0+(4−(1/2))(1/2).$$

Once you have all the values for $c_1, c_2, c_3, c_4$, you need to compute $M_n$ accordingly, where I am guessing $f$ refers to the integrand $x^2$, and $f(c_j)$ being the function $x^2$ evaluated at $x = c_j$.